# Taking two lines as the input

Tags: awk

If I have two lines in a file that look like this:

```
1 222 333
4 555 666
```

Is there a way to access these all at once such that:

`$1 = 1, $2 = 222, $3 = 333, $4 = 444, $5 = 555, $6 = 666`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you really have just two lines, or do you have a file with many pairs of lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your RS to a unique 8-bit ascii character value not present in it e.g.

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\xFF"}{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6}' file
```

Comment: This only works with `gwak`, since you are using more than one character for `RS`, and should be noted in the post.

Comment: @Jotne It works with other awks as well. Also, that's just one character.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with all `awk`, setting `RS` to nothing.

```
awk '{print $5}' RS="" file
555
```